# Function jquery and array()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

```
$.each(["a","b","c"],function(value){
    $("\"" + value + "\"").remove();
})
```

Hello to all. Why can not I make this code work? where am I wrong? thank you.

Comment: What's the problem? Do you get an error? The `$("\"" + value + "\"")` seems really strange.

Comment: For us to know what is wrong, it's helpful if you explain what it should be doing.  We have no clue.  Also `$('"a"')` isn't a valid selector

Comment: Actually, the problem is how I passed the string to the selector: wrong with double quotes, since the vector already containing strings is not needed!
I was creating a method to remove elements from the DOM at a given event. Since I was so many I thought about creating an array and then iterating it ... but I could not. Ps. it's not the first time I've done it but I've never come across a mistake (of course) so futile! thanks @Blundering Philosopher ... PPs sorry for my english is really bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter in the callback function is actually the `index` of the array. You should use the 2nd parameter, the array's `value`.

```
$.each(["a", "b", "c"], function(index, value) {
    // ...
})
```

Additionally, the `value` that comes back in that callback function is already a string (since the original array is an array of strings), so to find all of the `html` elements that match that `value` (as a `selector`), you can just use the plain `value` like this:

```
$(value) // ...
```

So you can put your statements together (and the `.remove` function) like this:

```
$.each(["a", "b", "c"], function(index, value) {
    $(value).remove();
});
```

**Note:** `"b"` and `"c"` are not valid selectors for `html` elements - maybe you're using those as placeholders?

Comment: No, no ... those selectors were just an example.